# Why doesn't tetrachloridotitanate(II) obey the 18-electron rule?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electronic-configuration, coordination-compounds

I have worked out that the complex comes to 10 electrons, however I do not understand why it does not obey the 18-electron rule? What are the factors that account for this?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Find out how to beautify your posts in the [help center](/help) and take the [tour] to learn more about this site. Enjoy!

Comment: My first comment is that the 18-electron rule has many more violations (e.g., typically 16-electron count for 4-coordinate complexes) than the octet rule.

Comment: But we also ask for your thoughts - why do you think the 18- or 16-electron count might be violated?

Comment: Tetra not trichlorotitanate?

Answer (score 5):

There is more to complex chemistry than the 18-electron rule. It states *one* condition when complexes may be particularly favourable, namely when all metal d-orbitals are fully populated and the ligands favourably interact with all metal s- and p-orbitals leading to all paired spins and hopefully a large energy difference between populated and unpopulated orbitals. The list of complexes that do *not* obey the 18-electron rule may well be larger than that of those that obey it. In no particular preference that includes $\ce{[MnO4]-}, \ce{[CrO4]^2-}, \ce{[Fe(CN)6]^3-}, \ce{[Mn(H2O)6]^2+}$ and many more. (A few of those are not typically described as complexes but they are nonetheless.)

Further constraints that you need to be aware of include, but are not limited to:

- steric stress, i.e. too many large ligands around too small a metal centre,
- charge density, i.e. surrounding a weakly charged cation with too many anions,
- the actual electronic configuration, which can render octahedral, Jahn–Teller-distorted octahedral or square planar complexes more favourable.

---

In the case of a chloridotitanate(II), we first need to realise that we are surrounding a moderately small cation (titanium(II)) with rather large anions (chloride) which may generate steric stress. We also need to observe that titanium(II) is only weakly charged and attempting to generate an octahedral configuration would give us an anion with $-4$ charge — not exactly favourable (exceptions may apply). Also, chlorido ligands are known to be weak-field ligands, so one would not expect an overly large crystal field split.

The two greatest factors are probably sterics and electronics. Consider tetrachloridocobaltate(III) $\ce{[CoCl4]-}$: while potentially six chlorides may fit around the rather small cation, even though it is $+3$ the electronic situation favours only tetracoordination. This results in a 14-electron complex rather than an 18-electron one. In analogy, I am tempted to say that the even lesser charged titanium(II) ion cannot accommodate for a total of six chlorides, allowing only four of them in its vicinity. Taking electronics into account, square planar coordination is out of the question due to lack of stabilising interactions and the complex would be tetrahedral.

In fact, the tetrahedral geometry allows for a mildly stabilised triplet state: both $\mathrm{e_g}$ orbitals are semipopulated which is generally a tad better than two of three $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ orbitals as it would be in the octahedral case.

Answer (score -1):

[TiCl4]2- is a weird one because rather than just using one effect for why its an exception it has two. It is both a pi donor ligand, and a high spin complex. I would go into more detail but its only one mark on the tutorial, so whats the point :/

Comment: Please go into more detail. It may be useful for future users and also for the OP in understanding the answer better.